# DataGrid選択時に、セルに配置したRadioButtonの文字色を変更したい

Tags: c#, wpf

DataGridの行を選択した際に、選択行の背景色を青、文字色を白にしていますが、
セルに配置しているradiobuttonの文字色も選択時に、白色に変更したいのですが
なかなか良い方法がみつかりません。どなたか良い方法をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら
教えて頂けないでしょうか？よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RelativeSource`を使用して`RadioButton`の上位にある`DataGridCell`や`DataGridRow`を参照すれば実現可能です。

例えば`DataGridCell.Foreground`には既定の文字色が反映されますので、これを`RadioButton.Foreground`にバインドすることが出来ます。

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton
                Content="radio"
                Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}, Path=Foreground}">
            </RadioButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

また`IsSelected`プロパティに`DataTrigger`を設定する方法でも実現できます。

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton
                Content="radio">
                <RadioButton.Style>
                    <Style
                        TargetType="RadioButton">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger
                                Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=IsSelected}"
                                Value="True">
                                <Setter
                                    Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="#fff" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </RadioButton.Style>
            </RadioButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: 頂いた内容で想定通りの動きになりました　ありがとうございました。